# having on the fly PERL spell checker in ultraedit (as in komodo edit)

Tags: perl, syntax, interactive, komodoedit, ultraedit

In Komodo Edit, the tool interactively informs you of syntax errors, many of them are just a typo. For example, let's say that I have typed (in PERL):

```
use strict;
my ($name);
$name1="Schuller";
```

In this case, there should be a red underline under $name1, as we have used strict, and $name1 was undefined.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UltraEdit doesn't do true syntax checking, unfortunately.

It just does syntax highlighting based on a regex search of the file using rules defined in the word files (perl.uew for perl).

So, it will highlight certain keywords in a syntax specific manner, but won't tell you if are writing bad code.